# PHP cURL use proxy to HTTPS website for example "www.google.com"

Tags: php, curl, https, proxy

I am trying to connect to an HTTPS site (eg google) using a proxy.
But it works only with HTTP sites, I searched for several solutions and none work

```
<?php
set_time_limit(180);

$proxy = "200.111.182.6:443";
$curl = curl_init("https://google.com");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$res = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

print $res;
```

Comment: I think do you need to specify proxy scheme.
Try with `$proxy = "https://200.111.182.6:443";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://google.com';
$proxyauth = 'user:pass';
$proxy = '200.111.182.6';
$proxyPort = '443';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//proxy suport
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxyPort);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
//https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);

$output = curl_exec($ch);   

if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}

echo $output;

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: This did not work for me, I get an HTTP status of 200 but an empty string returned instead of the $ouput content.